# How to draw "box"/square arrows in Chemdraw Prime 16.0?

Tags: software

I want to draw arrows like the one in the figure shown (with reagent *a* beside it) in ChemDraw 16.0[image]

What is the best way to go about this?

I couldn't find anything like it in the arrow options in ChemDraw Prime 16.0

Comment: Go into the icon that has circles and lines. Make a horizontal and vertical line segment. Make a right arrow. Put the three together with the lasso. Finally, group them so that it is reusable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*One* approach:

- draw the upper horizontal, then the vertical line to form the angle, e.g. using a single bond each time in anticlockwise direction.
- draw an reaction arrow «as usual» horizontally, pointing from the left to the right.  Depending on the style template, increasing the zoom may help to adjust its position relative to this angle when moving one of the two objects until the back of the arrow and the lower tip of the angle overlap.
- join arrow with the vertical of the angle constructed earlier into one object
- adjust size and position of this construct relative to the three text lines

While likely not designed for this purpose, it is possible to many molecular editors (not only ChemDraw) for a quick doodle / map about the buildings near the Chem department, or labels for the drawer because you can vertically / horizontally align shapes & objects quickly and export this in either vector, or bitmap format.

Be aware of one caveat: when structure cleaning, mark the true, meaningful structures, and not the whole page.  Or, instead of tearing a propane into said angle, use the line tool instead.  To some limited extent, this approach is working with the appetizer versions of [ChemDraw](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html#), and [ChemDoodle](https://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/2d-sketcher), too.